# How to use the Scanner to transfer JSON values in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, json

I want to send the value that I enter in the console using java in Eclipse.
`num` is a variable that uses Scanner to enter a value.
However, `num` does not appear to be used in the JSON syntax.
The meaning may not be conveyed well due to lack of English. Please excuse me.

I want to input the value from the Eclipse console and transfer the value through JSON. How should I fix it?

Error Notice:

> j_val is NULL; json_str={"number":num}

I'm not good enough because I just started learning. I look forward to your kind cooperation.

```
System.out.print("Please enter a number >> ");
int num = sc.nextInt();
String jdata = "{\"number\":num}"; //jdata == json_str
```

I solved the problem.

```
System.out.print("Please enter a number >> ");
int num = sc.nextInt();
String jdata = "{\"number\":"+num+"}"; //jdata == json_str
```

I lacked an understanding of the JSON syntax. Thank you.

Comment: If you simply want to insert the number into your `jdata` string then you need to concatenate the result with `"string" + num` like so: `String jdata = "{\"number\":" + num + "}";` note how `num` is inserted between  two different strings with +, which is the same as doing `String jdata = string1 + num + string2;`

Comment: Please learn from [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `String.format` like this:
`String jdata = String.format("{\"result:\":%d}", num);`

For example: `String json = String.format("{\"result\":%d}", 30);` will assign `{"result":30}` to `json`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a simple question, but I think I was flustered because I met a new syntax(JSON). Have a nice day!